# Evolution Calendar Notifications

Tags: notification, evolution, calendar

I have a strange problems. A year(maybe longer) I switched from Evolution to Thunderbird/Lighting. Uninstalled Evolution and all is fine. I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and now I am getting old recurring calendar notifications again. These are old ones that would have been in the old Evolution install.

I double checked and Evolution is still uninstalled. Opened dconf editor and it does have an evolution in it but not sure what if anything would be changed in it.

Any ideas on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may have removed the application, but you did not purge your calendars. The back-end service is still used by the rest of the system, for contacts and calendar.

If you remove the `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics` file, and the `~/.cache/evolution/calendar/` directory for your user, then log out, wait a few seconds, and log back in, you should no longer get any notifications about old calendar events from the local calendar you had been using in Evolution.