Evolution Problem
I am running 22.04.4 LTS. I keep getting out-of-date Evolution calendar updates.
Which is funny because neither Evolution emall nor calendar are set up on my machine, and when I search for them in software, I only get the option to install them.
When I click on the alerts, I cannot update, it does not take me to the app.
I don't know how Evolution got on my machine, how it got my calendar info, but I would like it to stop updating me. I have spent some time looking around, can't find any solutions.  In one forum I posted this problem, and the response was basically, "Wow. Good luck finding it."
Thanks.

possibly related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/453016/evolution-calendar-notifications
